# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-static-server'

Tags: react-native

Problem facing in the android app setup with error

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/rover/Desktop/appflow/node_modules/react-native-static-server/android/build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-static-server'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-static-server'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

I am getting this error on android while installing the app on the emulator. Checked with some online answers but not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is not good solution, but you can go inside of node modules and find your package, after open android folder and do the next instead of using:
apply plugin: 'maven'
you should use
apply plugin: 'maven-publish' and it will solve error. I will not recommend to do so, but it might help. Enjoy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).